# Create some custom actions in sbt?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have project of both .java and .scala files. They are in `src/`. Among those files, *several* of them are *main classes*, in that they have a `main` method, and can be run as a program. What I want is a convenient way to call/run each of them with a predefined set of parameters. For example:

```
  compiler.Compiler "tests/" "test-output/"
```

Where `Compiler` (in package `compiler`) has a main method `main(args: Array[String])`.

Is there an easy way to set up sbt so that I can run the above simply by typing: e.g. `kompiler`, in the sbt console?

Answer (score 0):

The homepage of the SBT project has a very good tutorial-style documentation. This should get you started: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Custom-Settings.html#implementing-a-task